# Hidden input field not binding value to field of DTO

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am making a quiz application which displays a list of questions along with their choices and then submitting the selected choices and the answers through a DTO.(Using lombok for getters and setters)

Question is a class:-

```
public class Question {
    
    @Id
    private int questionId;
    private String question;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    private List<Choice> choices;
    private String answer;
    private String questionType;
}
```

Choice is also a class:-

```
public class Choice {
    @Id
    private int choiceId;
    private String choice;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;
}
```

DTO that I am using to collect the choices and answers:-

```
public class formValues {
    private List<String> selectedChoices;
    private List<String> selectedAnswers;
    
    formValues(){
        selectedChoices = new ArrayList<String>();
        selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Through the controller I am sending a list of questions and iterating through them one by one, then I am assigning all the selected choices and answers to the two ArrayList of formValues DTO

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="result" th:object="${formValues}" method="post">
        <ul>

            <!-- Displaying questions -->

            <li th:each="obj : ${questions}">
                <h1 th:text="${obj.question}"></h1> 

                <!-- Displaying choices -->

                <ul>
                    <li th:each="choice : ${obj.choices}">
                    <label> 
                    <input type="radio"
                            th:field="*{selectedChoices[__${obj.questionId-1}__]}"
                            th:value="${choice.choice}"
                            th:name="'choice' + ${obj.questionId}"> 
                            <span th:text="${choice.choice}"></span>
                    </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{selectedAnswers[__${obj.questionId-1}__]}"
                        th:value="${obj.answer}" >
                        
            </li>
            
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the controller I am fetching the "formValue" object through @ModelAttribute and iterating through the lists of choices and answers but only the choices are being displayed. The ArrayList of answers has two blank elements. How do I assign the value of "obj.answer" to the "selectedAnswers" field of DTO???